# Sound doesn't work any more on my laptop on speakers neither on headphone

Tags: windows-10, speakers

As you see on the image, the sound seems to be working fine because the logo of the speaker does not show any errors, the problem appeared after a crash when I was editing a video for YouTube on OpenShot video editor.

When i restarted my laptop , it went directly to bios update and after Windows 10 started the sound just disappeared.

I don't know where the problem is coming from. I'm ready to give any other informations that is needed.

[image]

Comment: Try the audio troubleshooter: *Start > Troubleshooting > Troubleshoot audio playback* and follow the prompts.

Comment: One thing to try is to do a full shut-down (not the default, which is to hibernate), then remove the mains power and battery for at least 30 seconds. This will ensure that all the hardware, including audio, is in a fully reset state.

Comment: harrymc , i already tried this methode but it wasn't a success

Comment: AFH , i will try this , but i have an internal battery , should i wait till my laptop is discharged and then wait for 30 seconds to plug and restat it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good luck in the past with entering the Device Manager, identifying the failed device and uninstalling the driver by right clicking on the entry. Do not use the option to remove the install files when that option is presented.

On reboot, the computer will typically recognize the "missing" device and re-install the drivers, returning the audio functionality.

This problem has been common for my client base, specifically after Windows performs an update.

Comment: i already tried to update the driver , but it gives me a  message that the best driver is already installed .I guess im a gonna need to let the pc decharge after that im gonna wait like 30 seconds to start it , hoping that the problem is gonna be fixed